# Why is there no authentication for the asp.net 5.0 preview - web api template -

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I have created a web project in the new Visual Studio 2015.

I can choose asp.net 4.6 or 5.0 preview web api template. The old 4.6 has

authentication but I want to use the new 5.0 preview also web api.

But this template lacks the authentication, but why?

Comment: Because in the OWIN world you provide the Authentication you need when you need it.

Comment: did you hit `change authentication` on the new project window and pick an authentication scheme to include?

Comment: @Claies I could not hit "change authentication" because the button was disabled in asp.net 5.0 preview - web api template -.

Comment: @DavidL I guess that statement is never wrong: "You provide something when you need it" :P The asp.net 4.6 web api template also uses OWIN but I can change the authentication...

Comment: @Pascal Agreed :).  However, in all seriousness, this is the new paradigm of the ASP.NET 5 world.  "You are only provided what you explicitly say you need.  If you don't ask for it, you don't get it".  This is just another example of that mindset.

Comment: @DavidL Not sure... Is this not rather just a limitation of the asp.net 5.0 preview template? And how am I assumed to get authentication into the asp.net 5.0 preview template? Copy/paste from the working 4.6 template - LMAO...- This is the new world? OMGush!

Comment: @Pascal I can't say with 100% certainty, no, since I only am interpreting what I read from published sources :). It could be that they simply did not update the template.  I personally think that they deliberately left it out.  Regardless, I've added an answer with my take on it, as well as an example of adding cookie authentication.

Comment: @Pascal Please see my latest edit. I have added more background on the new ASP.NET 5 rewrite. I think this offers a more complete explanation of why the old authentication model has been scrapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OWIN world you provide the Authentication you need when you need it.  his is the new paradigm of the ASP.NET 5 world. "You are only provided what you explicitly say you need. If you don't ask for it, you don't get it". This is just another example of that mindset.

Scott Guthrie calls this out in his recent [post](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5):

> ASP.NET 5 introduces a new HTTP request pipeline that is modular so
> you can add only the components that you need. The pipeline is also no
> longer dependent on System.Web. By reducing the overhead in the
> pipeline, your app can experience better throughput and a more tuned
> HTTP stack. The new pipeline is based on many of the learnings from
> the Katana project and also supports OWIN.
>
> To customize which components are used in the pipeline, use the
> Configure method in your Startup class. The Configure method is used
> to specify which middleware you want to “use” in your request
> pipeline. ASP.NET 5 already includes ported versions of many of the
> middleware from the Katana project, like middleware for static files,
> authentication and diagnostics. The following image shows some of the
> features you can add or remove to the pipeline for your project.

You can plug in your security very quickly; you just need to specify what it is that you'll be using.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // Add static files to the request pipeline.
    app.UseStaticFiles();
 
    // Add cookie-based authentication to the request pipeline.
    app.UseIdentity();
 
    // Add MVC and routing to the request pipeline.
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

They did deliberately leave it out as it is not how ASP.NET is built to work anymore. It is a complete rewrite that no longer has a dependency on System.Web which would be needed for the previous security templates to work. The framework takes what they learnt from OWIN and incorporates that. ASP.NET 5 framework is the new breed of OWIN. But middleware is added exactly the same. Previous middleware libraries for OWIN should work in ASP.NET 5.

@Pascal what @DavidL means is that in your web app's pipeline you add authentication as middleware. You do this as an extension method on IAppBuilder.

First you will need to add the authentication library as a dependency in your project.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-*",
```

Then you should look at the examples on the official [MicroSoft ASP.NET Security GitHub page](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/samples/CookieSample/Startup.cs)

Look at the lines:

```
 using Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies;
```

and:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
        });

        app.Run(async context =>
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.User.Identity.Name))
            {
                var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "bob") }));
                       context.Authentication.SignIn(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, user);
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello First timer");
                return;
            }

            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello old timer");
        });
```

This should come before app.UseMvc() in an MVC 6 web app.
I hope this helps :)

Comment: Just because they changed the way authentication works, that doesn't automatically mean that they need to exclude authentication from their templates. They could just update the template code to use the new method of authentication (like they have with the mvc project template).

Comment: @rdans correct! Even more why has preview templates no unit test projects I want to add? Is this also the new paradigm... and why has the preview templates references to the old SYSTEM.WEB.XXX ? ah because we are in OWIN world right...

Answer (score 1):

It is still an option when you select the mvc project template in asp.net 5. So just use the mvc template and add your web api controllers in there. Web api and mvc use the same controllers in v5 anyway. Of course you will probably want to modify some of the auth controllers to return json instead of views to be more suitable for a web api.

MS have made a lot of changes to the identity system in preparation for asp.net 5 so it doesn't make sense to me that they would exclude it from their templates (at least as an option - which is what it has always been). I expect they have not gotten around to updating the templates yet.

From the github readme:

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity

> ASP.NET Identity is the new membership system for building ASP.NET web applications. ASP.NET Identity allows you to add login features to your application and makes it easy to customize data about the logged in user.
>
> This project is part of ASP.NET vNext. You can find samples, documentation and getting started instructions for ASP.NET vNext at the Home repo.