# steps to enable windows authentication on IIS 8 for a web api asp.net 5 site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Trying to do the simplest possible test case to get the logged in user name in a Web API ASPNET 5 template, after it's hosted on IIS 8.

So this works on my local (IIS Express)

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {            
        var name = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        return new string[] { name, "value2" };
    }
```

but when I deploy to the server (having only Windows Authentication enabled) it shows the name as the IIS Apppool identity for the site.

I reviewed this answer [Why is there no authentication for the asp.net 5.0 preview - web api template -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200862/why-is-there-no-authentication-for-the-asp-net-5-0-preview-web-api-template) but I'm not sure if it will work specifically for Windows Authentication.

Just need some direction, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your app includes `app.UseIISPlatformHandler()` (beta8 or later). Then check `HttpContext.User`.